# django auth tables created in public schema instead of non-public schema

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create all Django tables in a new schema that is not the `public` schema. When I define the new schema in `search_path` in my db connection settings, I get error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in`

I am able to create a new schema and some tables in this new schema from a `migrations/0001_initial.py` file, if I include `public` in the `search_path`:

```
def create_schema(apps, schema_editor):
    # create onboarding schema
    schema = "onboarding"
    try:
        schema_editor.execute("DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS %s CASCADE" % schema)
        schema_editor.execute("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %s" % schema)
        print("The onboarding schema has successfully been created!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_schema),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Agency',
            ...
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Employee'
        )
    ]
```

where my settings file is setup as follows for the db section:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": ...
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'options': '-c search_path=onboarding,public'
        },
        "NAME": ...
        "USER": ...
        "PASSWORD": ...
        "HOST": ...
        "PORT": ...
    }
}
```

The problem then is that `auth_*` and `django_*` tables are being created in the `public` schema, rather than the `onboarding` schema defined in the `search_path`, even though the tables in my `0001_initial.py` do get created in the new schema.

I am setting this app from scratch, so is there a way to tell Django to use a specific schema for all its db transactions and not `public`?